# If a matrix diagonalises both matrices, do they diagonalise to the same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I stumbled upon this problem in my head, while proving that if there exists a basis of $K^{n\times 1}$, which consists of shared eigenvectors of $A \in K^{n\times n}$ and  $B \in K^{n\times n}$, then $A$ and $B$ commute. I managed to prove this, by saying that this basis, lets call it $C$ diagonalises both $A$ and $B$, such that $C^{-1}AC = D_1$ and $C^{-1}BC = D_2$, whereas $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal matrices.

My question is, are $D_1$ and $D_2$ the same, and if not: Why? I thought that if I have a basis $C$ that diagonalises $A$, then $C^{-1}AC = D_1 = diag(t_1,t_2, ... , t_n)$ with $t_i$ being eigenvalues of $A$. If I do this for both $A$ and $B$, intuitively I think that I would end up with the same matrix, which would mean that $A$ and $B$ are the same matrices, just written in another basis.

Comment: You should be able to prove this false just by starting from the opposite conclusion. Try taking the identity (2x2) matrix $diag(1, 1)$ and then the matrix $diag(1,2)$ and then conjugate them by the same matrix $C$ to get matrices $A$ and $B$ that commute but don't diagonalize to the same matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are already diagonal, then $C=C^{-1}=I$ and $D_1, D_2$ are not the same.